# Is the issue of self force on point charges solved by QED?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, self-energy

I know that classically self force is not a very tractable problem for point particles, although some attempts have been made in various ways over the years.

I also know that even in QED renormalization is needed to get rid of infinities in energies caused by this interaction.

However, does QED actually predict, for example, a braking force on a single accelerating electron? I know obviously force is ill defined in QED, but some analog of a prediction? I can’t seem to find an answer to this anywhere I look.

Just from a simple consideration it seems like this shouldn’t happen since, I believe a single electron emitting a photon can’t conserve both total momentum and energy, but that is a bit of a digression.

Comment: Even before invoking QED, in a generic quantum theory, there are structural issues with statements like 'single' and 'point' charges. The uncertainty principle forbids us from localizing a particle to a 'point' precision. Also, as you probe higher and higher energies, you can no longer say that you have a 'single' particle in the region of interest (because of pair production, etc.).

Comment: "a single electron emitting a photon can’t conserve both total momentum and energy," thats true, there has to be an interaction with another particle or a field to balance momentum. . see pair production from a single photon for the concept https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Cross_section